# display 'make' output in 'vim'

Tags: vim, makefile

I want to :make and display output from it only if it fails.

I map  to

```
:wa<cr>:make<cr><cr>
```

and only when it fails I want to see the results. Notice the

```
<cr><cr>
```

sequence, which closes the output because usually it's success and nothing to read. And it's much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `:silent` to stop the output and use `:cwindow` to open the quickfix window when there is something to see.

```
:wa|silent make|cwindow<cr>
```

Note: you will want to use `<bar>` instead of `|` if this is inside a mapping. Example of a mapping below:

```
nnoremap <f9> :wa<bar>silent make<bar>cwindow<cr>
```

See the following for more information:

```
:h :silent
:h :cw
```

Comment: I use it like this `map <F9> :wa<cr>:silent make<bar>cwindow<cr>`
and it hangs out VIM.

Comment: If I change it like this `map <F9> :wa<cr>:silent !make<bar>cwindow<cr>` it doesn't hang but doesn't work either.

Comment: I was missing a `:` or `<bar>` however you look at it. I have added an example mapping.

Comment: OK, now I see it works, but only with specific errors. For example when gcc reports an error in the line number 10. That works in gvim (terminal vim needs screen refresh C-l). But in a case of any other error it doesn't catch it. Try remove one source file and produce this error: `make: *** No rule to make target `1.cc', needed by `1.exe'.  Stop.`. Vim will not catch it.

Comment: My project is a coffee scripts, jade pages, and CSSOnDiet preprocessor. Non of them generates structured output like gcc. So I guess my question should be more generic. Not about `make` but about any external script which output has to be catches when fail.

Comment: @TomekWyderka, see `:help :make` an `:help errorformat`. Also do you know about [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)?

Comment: You can always setup a compiler for a linter of your choice and also adjust `'errorformat'` as @romainl suggests (See `:h write-compiler-plugin`). He also recommends Syntastic which is a good plugin in its own right however you can also steal the `'errorformat'` and `'makeprg'` settings from if you would rather use `:make`. Optionally you may be interested in using something like [Dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch).