# display STDOUT in vim when external command fails

Tags: vim, sh

I need to run external command in vim and see the stdout only if it fails.

For example when I hit F9 i want to run `do.sh` and be informed only about the errors. Now I use double `<cr><cr>` to close the default output window but this will not show me any errors:

```
nmap <F9> :!./script.sh<cr><cr>
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask this, or a very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041129/display-make-output-in-vim ?

Comment: No. This is a different question. Just a bit similar. Solution from there will not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done easily with the `system()` function and the `v:shell_error` variable. Put the following in your .vimrc file.

```
nnoremap <leader>n :call Foo()<cr>

function! Foo()
  let bar = system('script.sh')
  if v:shell_error
    echo bar
  endif
endfunction
```

As a bonus, there's no need for the double `<cr>` because system() returns the output without displaying anything.

Answer (score 2):

Use the tool that does the thing well: the shell. A wrapper like this may do the trick:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #
 # Run the program specified by the args silently and show stdout on failure.

 if ! "$@" >stdout 2>stderr; then
    cat stdout stderr
 fi
```

You might be able to cram this in a vim mapping. A slightly shorter version could be:

```
 ./script.sh > stdout || cat stdout
```